# Office graph inconsistency in rquests

Tags: office-365, search-api, office-graph

If I have a request like

```
myDomain/_api/search/query?Querytext='*'&Properties='GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\,action\:1001)'
```

retrieve different results that this query

```
myDomain/_api/search/query?Querytext='*'&amp;Properties='GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\,action\:1001)'
```

Even when it's the same request and the only different is that I'm passing the "&" as "&".

Does somebody know what's the reason for this?

The problem with this is I'm not able to pass the first query through GET Request (using jquery ajax) because I'm receiving an Internal Error server code [500]

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same issue with office graph query.

Please try with following url.

> &Properties='GraphQuery:ACTOR(ME\\,action\\:1001)'

Instead of single escape character `'\'`, use two escape characters `'\\'`.

And **don't use  & amp;** in query, as it will not consider parameters provided after **& amp;**. And it will return normal search results, not Office Graph results.